# Spring 3 and hibernate 4.X facing a transaction Manager Exception in destroy-method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

We are currently using Spring 3 with hibernate 4.4 in our project. 
A snippet of my database config xml looks as follows

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass">
            <value>${jdbc.driver.className}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl">
            <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">managed</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.sample.entity" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
```

While we were testing our war , we came across this exception .

```
13:27:19,511 ERROR TransactionInterceptor:419 - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Singleton bean creation not allowed 
    while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a 
    BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:212)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:248)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:100)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
```

I am unable to figure out if this is because of the destroy-method =close mentioned in the config file . I am also using the @Transactional annotation at both the Service layer and the database layer . Will this cause any issue? 
We were trying to test a scenario where in multiple people (around 150) are all trying to access our application at the same time.

Kindly help me out.. Please do let me know, If more details are needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the spring doc says in [Section 3.6.1.5](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor)

> The order of startup and shutdown invocations can be important. If a "depends-on"           relationship exists between any two objects, the dependent side will start after its dependency, and it will stop before its dependency. However, at times the direct dependencies are unknown. You may only know that objects of a certain type should start prior to objects of another type. In those cases, the SmartLifecycle interface defines another option, namely the getPhase() method as defined on its super-interface, Phased.

So you need the bean to implement the SmartLifeCycle, Javadoc for SmartLifeCycle Interface  [1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor): http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anugoonj .. But just wanted to know , isnt there any configuration changes that can be made? Or is implementing the SmartLifecycle the only way to resolve this error